# Unable to select checkbox via jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

this might be relatively simple, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's my Code

```js
$(":checkbox").change(function(e) {
  alert("as");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_selector" id="<?php echo $products->ProductID; ?>">
```

but i do not get any alert. What wrong am I doing?

Comment: try $('input[type="checkbox"]')

Comment: it's working fine in snippet check it  http://jsfiddle.net/sanchitpatiyal95/s6fe9/1054/

Comment: Where's that `<script>` tag embedded? In the beginning of the file (in `<head>`), or at the end (before closing `<body>` tag)?

Comment: @MichałKostrzyński
It's before <body>

Comment: Put it on the end. Just before the `<body>` ends and it will most probably work. Also you should wrap the whole thing (as one of the answers below suggest) in the `$(document).ready` handling function as there's a possibility it will fire before the DOM tree is parsed and won't work, as there won't be any checkbox yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this inside document.ready function 
Like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ":checkbox" ).change(function(e){
    alert("as");
  });
});
```